# Selenium: How to set test on dropdown box?

Tags: spring, combobox, selenium, drop-down-menu, selenium-ide

In **Spring** I generated form create.jspx with some edit boxes and some dropdown select boxes.
The form than sould be tested in **Selenium IDE**, but after recording test case the case cant' be replayed.

For example, form:
Label1: [Sample text]
Label2: [Selected_item0]

Selenium recording would be:

`click | Edit1_id        |

type  | Edit1_id        |Sample text

click | Edit2_id_popup0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out :)

```
<tr>  
  <td>clickAt</td>  
  <td>//div[@id='widget__edit2_id']/div[1]/input</td>  
  <td>0,0</b>  
</td>  
</tr>  
<tr>  
  <td>waitForVisible</td>    
  <td>_edit2_id_popup1</td>  
  <td></td>  
</tr>
  <tr>  
  <td>mouseOver</td>    
  <td>_edit2_id_popup1</td>  
  <td></td>  
</tr>  
<tr>  
  <td>clickAt</td>  
  <td>_edit2_id_popup1</td>  
  <td>0,0</td>  
</tr>
```